# Bash: how to configure a keyboard shortcut to run a program and insert its output at the position of cursor?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

When typing a command in Bash, I would like to be able to press a combination of keys to run a program and insert the output of the program to the command line at the position of the cursor.
For instance:

```
$ cat <Ctrl-G>
# bash runs a program that prints "some-file" to stdout
$ cat some-file
```

I would like it to work for every command - not only `cat`.

I tried the following approach:

```
bind -x '"\C-g":"echo some-file"'
```

but "some-file" is printed to the terminal not the command line:

```
$ cat <Ctrl-G>
some-file
$ cat
```

Comment: would `$( ... )` work for you, like `cat $( some-program )`?

Comment: Good idea, but the goal of this is to make life easier: the fact the program is started by running Ctrl-G is crucial for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in `READLINE_LINE` and `READLINE_POINT` variables set by [bind](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins):

> -x keyseq:shell-command
>
> Cause shell-command to be executed whenever keyseq is entered. When shell-command is executed, the shell sets the READLINE_LINE variable to the contents of the Readline line buffer and the READLINE_POINT variable to the current location of the insertion point. If the executed command changes the value of READLINE_LINE or READLINE_POINT, those new values will be reflected in the editing state.

For example:

```
stuff() { 
    local pre="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}"
    local suf="${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
    local stuff='my string here'
    READLINE_LINE="${pre}$stuff$suf"
    ((READLINE_POINT += ${#stuff}))
}

bind -x '"\C-g":"stuff;"'
```

Credits to Greg Wooledge who replied to my question in [help-bash mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2020-03/msg00050.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have Lubuntu and so X windows, OpenBox and I solve this problem by having shortcuts defined in Openbox.

```
nano ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
#setting shortcuts to point at a special bash script
openbox --reconfigure # restart shortcuts
```

So if I press ctrl+G anywhere it runs the given script
which outputs the result into a clipboard, say:

```
 echo "Hello World at $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)" | xsel -b -i
```

Then I paste the output in Bash terminal (ctrl+shift+V).

I know it is not pure BASH, but it may help you somehow.

PS. If I need to send keys directly to an application, I use **xdotool**.